# remote module not found webpack 5 module federation

Tags: angular, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

```
Getting below error when loading the remote module, 
core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for
```

'RegisterPageModule'.
Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'RegisterPageModule'.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the following command :  ng generate module RegisterPageModule
Please show us the Code of your RegisterPageModule.

You can try :

1. Clearing your npm cache
2. reinstalling all node_modules
3. checking your "include" and "files" tsconfig setting etc
   and you're still having issues, and you are Lazy Loading Modules check your angularCompilerOptions in your tsconfig.json or tsconfig.app.json, and make sure that "strictMetadataEmit" is set to false or is removed.

   ```
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    // "strictMetadataEmit": true <-- remove this setting or set to false
   },
   ```

It might help to look into the angular reference on how to make a feature module : https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules

Heres the angular document for lazy loading modules https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: HI @Steve, I am trying to implement micro frontend using webpack build and serve getting this error. Same is working fine when angular cli (ngx-build-plus)